# SQL Comparing COUNT values within same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve a seemingly simple problem, but I think i'm tripping over on my understanding of how the EXISTS keyword works. The problem is simple (this is a dumbed down version of the actual problem) - I have a table of students and a table of hobbies. The students table has their student ID and Name. Return only the students that share the same number of hobbies (i.e. those students who have a unique number of hobbies would not be shown)

So the difficulty I run into is working out how to compare the count of hobbies. What I have tried is this.

```
SELECT sa.studentnum, COUNT(ha.hobbynum)
FROM student sa, hobby ha
WHERE sa.studentnum = ha.studentnum
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM student sb, hobby hb
            WHERE sb.studentnum = hb.studentnum 
            AND sa.studentnum != sb.studentnum
            HAVING COUNT(ha.hobbynum) = COUNT(hb.hobbynum)
           )
GROUP BY sa.studentnum
ORDER BY sa.studentnum;
```

So what appears to be happening is that the count of hobbynums is identical each test, resulting in all of the original table being returned, instead of just those that match the same number of hobbies.

Comment: You're just comparing the count of hobbies between two students. Is that enough? I mean what about the type of that hobby? I like studying and somebody else like swimming, are we both the same in your point of view?!

Comment: Yes - just the count in this instance. Actual hobby doesn't matter. This is a simplified version of the actual problem.

Comment: Simplified version of the problem is more confusing. I'd suggest you to come with the real situation, where we can talk about what you need to change.

Comment: I agree with Mohammad, it's not clear what you want.  When you say "return only the students that share the same number of hobbies", do you have some number in mind? It would be easy to find all students with exactly one (or two or ten) hobbies).

Comment: Oh yes - that would be easier. :) Yeah - the actual problem is related to event sales - I am doing some analysis to look at individuals that bought tickets in similar quantities. So it's not the number that matter - it's the fact that a customer bought the same number of tickets as another customer to the same event. It's a looooooong story.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but maybe something like this (if I understand the problem correctly):

```
WITH h AS (
  SELECT studentnum, COUNT(hobbynum) OVER (PARTITION BY studentnum) student_hobby_ct
    FROM hobby)
SELECT studentnum, student_hobby_ct
  FROM h h1 JOIN h h2 ON h1.student_hobby_ct = h2.student_hobby_ct AND
                         h1.studentnum <> h2.studentnum;
```

Comment: Interesting - I believe that would work. Thank you - Can you enlighten me as to why the other syntax wouldn't produce a similar result?

Comment: This syntax works because it is essentially doing a self join.  The other one doesn't because it is not doing a self join.  The exists keyword is useful for many situations, such as preventing duplicate inserts.  It is not appropriate for what you are attempting.

Comment: I don't see how your query above works at all. I assume you meant to have a GROUP BY inside the parens of your subquery. Remember that the EXISTS clause will return TRUE/SUCCESS if a ROW is returned by the subquery, so unless the inner query is correlated to the outer somehow, it will always return success.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what your query would do is only return students who had at least one other student that had the same number of hobbies.  But you're not returning anything about the students with whom they match.  Is that intentional?  I'd treat both queries as sub-queries     and aggregate before a join on the counts.  You could do several things... here it's returning the number of students that have matching hobby counts, but you could limit HAVING(COUNT(distinct sb.studentnum) = 0 to get the result your query seemed to return...

```
with xx as 
(SELECT sa.studentnum, count(ha.hobbynum) hobbycount
            FROM student sa inner join hobby ha
            on sa.studentnum = ha.studentnum
            group by sa.studentnum
           )
select sa.studentnum, sa.hobbycount, count(distinct sb.studentnum) as matchcount
from
xx sa inner join xx sb on 
    sa.hobbycount = sb.hobbycount
where
    sa.studentnum != sb.studentnum
GROUP by sa.studentnum, sa.hobbycount
ORDER BY sa.studentnum;
```

Comment: Ah, I hate it when someone else posts a working answer while I'm typing.  With shorter syntax, too.  ;-)